# How to calculate moving median with percentile_disc() and window?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

The window is working with COUNT, AVG, etc. but not works with percentile_disc

```
  SELECT
       x,
       COUNT(*) OVER w AS w_count, -- fine
       AVG(x) OVER w   AS avg_x,     -- fine
       percentile_disc(0.5) within group (order by x) OVER w AS mdn_x  -- BUG!
  FROM t
  WINDOW w AS (ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
  ORDER BY 1
```

(edited),

- PostgreSQL v10.12  say   *syntax error at or near "OVER"*.
- PostgreSQL v12.2  say *OVER is not supported for ordered-set aggregate percentile_disc*

Seems that is not possible... There are some workaround? Perhaps a lateral join with a subquery.

---

As [explained here](https://anomaly.io/moving-median-robust-anomaly/index.html), **the MEDIAN is important**, better tham AVG in anomaly analysis. As well the [moving median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Moving_median), better (most resilient) tham moving average.

Comment: I get "*OVER is not supported for ordered-set aggregate percentile_disc*" https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=35f2aed6ccd2ed3f713a1af5bbfb1cb8

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, I edited... You suggest a workaround? In the real world it's a need for [*moving average*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) and a [*moving median*](https://anomaly.io/moving-median-robust-anomaly/index.html) in the same query.

Answer (score 2):

I just thought of yet another possibility. We can create an aggregate and use it just like built-in `avg` or `count`.

Let's start with an aggregator:

```
create function median_sfunc (
    state integer[], data integer
) returns integer[] as
$$
begin
    if state is null then
        return array[data];
    else
        return state || data;
    end if;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

And then the finisher:

```
create function median_ffunc (
    state integer[]
) returns double precision as
$$
begin
    return (state[(array_length(state, 1) + 1)/ 2] + state[(array_length(state, 1) + 2) / 2]) / 2.;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Of course the supplier (initial state) will be the empty query. Thus we get the aggregate:

```
create aggregate median (integer) (
    sfunc     = median_sfunc,
    stype     = integer[],
    finalfunc = median_ffunc
    );
```

Now you can call it in an elegant way no matter the window you're using:

```
select x,
       count(*) over w as w_count,
       avg(x) over w as avg_x,
       median(x) over w as mdn_x
from tmp t
    window w as (order by x rows between 3 preceding and current row)
```

Comment: Hi, perfect! The only adaptations I made for use in real life, generalizing to "any numeric type", were `FUNCTION median_sfunc (state anyarray, data anyelement) RETURNS anyarray`, etc. and add `IMMUTABLE` clause. It is not relevant, I used also `language SQL` (with simple `SELECT CASE`), because I prefer the standard SQL whenever possible ... and also  renamed to `smallSeq_median` to remember that is a workaround for small numeric sequences, to take care with big windows on Big Data.

Comment: @PeterKrauss you're right, that's even more general, feel free to edit my answer to change the types;)

Comment: Thanks @Andronicus, there are another interesting  issues and a little error in your simplification, please check/collabore with the [Wiki answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61573544/287948).

Answer (score 2):

### So you need a median filter

Let's specify the task first. A median filter should follow requested rows order (order by date, by id or whatever you need), while value that should be filtered can be considered random. If value filtered is only increasing, what you need median filter for anyway? :)

**tl;dr** see [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=93cd0f991483d765222941a90071b029) with all examples

We basically need `SELECT median(x) OVER window_n`, but there's no built-in function in postgresql like that.

### Simplest workaround

```
SELECT id, x, 
    (SELECT percentile_cont(0.5) within group (ORDER BY s)
    FROM unnest(arr) t(s)) as median
FROM (
    SELECT id, x, array_agg(x) over w as arr
    FROM tmp
    WINDOW w as (rows between N-1 preceding and current row)
    ORDER BY id
) t
ORDER BY id
```

Using `percentile_cont()` over `unnest()` does the trick, but we need nested `select`. Note that for filter window width `N` you should set `N-1 preceding` rows.

**Performance:** `Execution Time: 738.966 ms` for 100 000 rows selected with `N=5` (from big table with 5M+ rows). With bigger window size `N` performance will be obviously worse.

Using pre-defined aggregate from other answer gave me 2100-2500 ms on same data.

You can instead use manual array sorting, something like `select array_agg(s) from (select s from unnest(arr) t(s) order by x)`, and computing median from array elements by indexes `(s[floor((w_count+1)*0.5)] + s[ceil((w_count+1)*0.5)]) / 2`, but performance will be roughly the same. For better performance you need faster array sorting.

### Faster workaround for integers

Extension `intarray` (included in postgresql) can be user for fast array sorting.

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;
```

Unfortunately, it works only with integer arrays, but in some cases it can be used with floats. For example, if you need only 3 decimals, multiply your float by 1000, convert to int, compute median, divide by 1000.

```
SELECT id, x, 
    ((
       sorted[floor((w_count+1)*0.5)] 
     + sorted[ceil((w_count+1)*0.5)]
    )::float / 2.) as median
FROM (
    SELECT id, x, 
        sort(array_agg(x) over w) as sorted,
        count(*) over w as w_count
    FROM tmp
    WINDOW w as (rows between N-1 preceding and current row)
    ORDER BY id
) t
ORDER BY id
```

**Performance**: `Execution Time: 350.480 ms` on same data, 100 000 rows, N=5. Two times faster!

### Why lag() doesn't work

Well, it's clever idea to use `lag()` function to compute median. It's similar to accessing array element by index, only without array, directly inside window.

Unfortunately, for it to work you need for values in window to be sorted by your `x`, and windows itself ordered by your common sorting key in query, and you cannot do both.

When using `WINDOW w as (order by x rows between N-1 preceding and current row)` you are sorting not just rows inside window. It affects order in which rows are selected for window. In other words, you are sorting ALL rows by x, then select a window over them. It's not what you would want for median filter.

See the last example in [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=93cd0f991483d765222941a90071b029)
And even performance in my case was worse than with `intarray`.

Answer (score 1):

@Andronicus pointed the best "workaround strategies", but general solution need polymorphic datatypes and  some fine ajust. With version 9.3+ PostgreSQL we can also optimize the aggregate calculus on windows (Moving-Aggregate Mode), that is important for a workaround.

### This is the correct solution

This  solution is the best that we can do in nowadays (year 2020), it is only a  "good and reliable workaround": please **let the PostgreSQL developers know** (RAM and CPU consumptions).

```sql
create or replace FUNCTION smallseq_agg_sfunc (
    state anyarray, data anyelement
) RETURNS anyarray as $f$
  SELECT   state || data
$f$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;

create or replace FUNCTION array_median(state anyarray) returns anyelement as $f$
  SELECT percentile_cont(0.5) within group (ORDER BY s)
  FROM unnest(state) t(s)
$f$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;

create or replace AGGREGATE smallset_median (anyelement) (
  sfunc     = smallseq_agg_sfunc,
  stype     = anyarray,
  finalfunc = array_median,
  initcond  = '{}'
);
```

A name prefix like `smallset_`  is important to remember that it is a workaround, valid only for *small sets* or ordered  *small sequences*. When it is small, no problem in reorder an ordered sequence.  In a context of Big Data (big windows or big tables), we must to [check performance of this workaround](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html).

> The order characterizes the median operation, is very important, and in a [window](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) or `GROUP BY` clause is usual to mix many variables (many orders), so the `order by` is useful in a function of general-use library.  You can [replace AVG](https://anomaly.io/moving-median-robust-anomaly/index.html) without fear!

### Didactic comments

Mathematicians [define the mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Finite_data_set_of_numbers)  as

[image]

so, we can implement it and avoid the `order by` clause for ordered sequences:

```sql
create or replace FUNCTION smallseq_percentile_cont (
    state anyarray 
) returns double precision as $f$
  SELECT ( s[floor((up+1)*0.5)] + s[ceil((up+1)*0.5)] )::double precision / 2.
  FROM ( SELECT array_agg(x) FROM unnest(state) t(x)) ) t1(s)
       , ( SELECT array_upper(state,1) ) t2(up)
$f$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Please avoid to simplify by `(s[(up + 1)/ 2] + s[(up + 2) / 2])`, it is not correct.
You can replace the `0.5` by a parameter to obtain the [`percentile_cont(fraction)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) analog. For an unordered sets (`smallset_percentile_cont` implementation) you can add `ORDER BY x` after `t(x)`.

### More general cases

Is important to remember that "classic median" is based on *continuous percentile* (cont), but there are also the *discrete percentile* (disc).

The build-in function `percentile_cont()` not make sense for `text` datatype and others, and sometimes we need to preserve median in the same datatype (e.g. integer and not double), or use a sample element. In this context we are thinking about the `percentile_disc()`. Suppose also that, as useful generic array function, we prefer parametric one:

```sql
create or replace FUNCTION array_percentile_disc(
  state anyarray, p float DEFAULT 0.5
) returns anyelement as $f$
  SELECT percentile_disc(p) within group (ORDER BY s)
  FROM unnest(state) t(s)
$f$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;

create or replace FUNCTION array_median_disc(state anyarray)
returns anyelement as $wrap$
  SELECT array_percentile_disc($1)
$wrap$ language SQL IMMUTABLE;

create or replace AGGREGATE smallset_median_disc (anyelement) (
  sfunc     = smallseq_agg_sfunc,
  stype     = anyarray,
  finalfunc = array_median_disc,
  initcond  = '{}'
);
```

There are [another **problem with PostgreSQL**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411209/pass-extra-parameter-to-postgresql-aggregate-final-function/46412594#comment108908091_46412594): it is impossible to define a *second parameter for finalfunc*, so, if you need for example to define `AGGREGATE smallseq_percentile_disc(anyelement,float)` you need to define each one, for example for "90% discrete" define more one wrap function `array_perc90_disc()` using `array_percentile_disc($1,0.9)`.

### Moving-Aggregate Mode option

See [Pg Guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xaggr.html#XAGGR-MOVING-AGGREGATES).

... please collabore here: this answer is a Wiki!

### Big Data workaround

As @Andronicus suggested, we can use `lag()`. In this case is important also to remember to check  the order of the window, maybe you need a specific window for median.

```sql
SELECT x, avg_x,
       CASE WHEN w_count<9001 THEN NULL ELSE mdn_x END mdn_x 
FROM (
  SELECT x,
       count(*) over w   AS w_count,
       avg(x)   over w   AS avg_x,
       (
         lag(x, floor(9002*0.5)::double precision / 2.) over w 
         + lag(x, ceil(9002*0.5)::double precision / 2.) over w 
       ) / 2.            AS mdn_x
  FROM t
  WINDOW w as (ORDER BY x rows between 9000 preceding and current row)
) t_aux
```

We can use `w_count` to generalize and avoid initial nulls, and now supposing also a "discrete median", we can use:

```sql
SELECT x, w_count, avg_x,
       lag( x, floor(w_count*0.5) ) over w2 AS mdn_x
FROM (
  SELECT x,
       count(*) over w   AS w_count,
       avg(x)   over w   AS avg_x
  FROM t
  WINDOW w1 as (rows between 9000 preceding and current row)
) t_aux
WINDOW w2 as (ORDER BY x rows between 9000 preceding and current row)
```

Important that `w2` is a clone of `w1`, except by the ORDER clause.

Comment: For other workarounds, using `first_value()` and `percent_rank()`, see [this blog post about "How to Emulate PERCENTILE_DISC in MySQL"](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/01/28/how-to-emulate-percentile_disc-in-mysql-and-other-rdbms/).

Comment: `lag(x, floor(w_count*0.5)) over (ORDER BY x rows ... )` cannot be used as median filter, because it orders ALL rows by `x`, not just those inside window. And you want your median filter to follow original row order (sorted by time or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ordered-set aggregate functions do not support windows. You can compute it by hand as a workaround:

```
select x,
       count(*) over w as w_count,
       avg(x) over w   as avg_x,
       (lag(x, 2) over w + lag(x) over w) / 2. as mdn_x
from tmp t
    window w as (rows between 3 preceding and current row)
order by 1;
```

Here is a [working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d3fc402d43390bcb3f4e624891a2dd3c). This does not work for the first 3 rows though. If you want it to work for every row, then the corner cases need to be checked:

```
select x,
       count(*) over w as w_count,
       avg(x) over w   as avg_x,
       case
           when lag(x) over w is null then x
           when lag(x, 2) over w is null then (x + lag(x) over w) / 2.
           when lag(x, 3) over w is null then lag(x) over w
           else (lag(x, 2) over w + lag(x) over w) / 2.
           end
from tmp t
    window w as (rows between 3 preceding and current row)
order by 1;
```

Here is a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=59ce5ab15668d755892c6c7c946275f8).

Of course your example is quite easy, because the window is not large (only 4 elements), but the exact query gets really long for larger windows.

Edit:

The first query can be generalized as:

```
select x,
       count(*) over w as w_count,
       avg(x) over w   as avg_x,
       (lag(x, (N + 1) / 2) over w + lag(x, N / 2) over w) / 2. as mdn_x
from tmp t
    window w as (rows between N preceding and current row)
order by 1;
```

where `N` is the number of rows to look back. This holds for even `N`, but in that case, the last column can be simplified to:

```
lag(x, N / 2) over w as mdn_x
```

The exact query would have to be rewritten as:

```
select x,
       count(*) over w as w_count,
       avg(x) over w   as avg_x,
       case
           when lag(x) over w is null then x
           when lag(x, 2) over w is null then (x + lag(x) over w) / 2.
           -- other terms
           when lag(x, N) over w is null then (lag(x, (N - 1) / 2) over w + lag(x, N / 2) over w) / 2.
           else (lag(x, 2) over w + lag(x) over w) / 2.
           end
from tmp t
    window w as (rows between N preceding and current row)
order by 1;
```

with the general formula for corner cases:

```
when lag(x, M) over w is null then (lag(x, (m - 1) / 2) over w + lag(x, m / 2) over w) / 2.
```

I cannot think of any method other than metaprogramming / dynamic query in this case. When the window reaches following rows, the formula gets more complicated, because depending on the sign of rows preceding and following - `lag` or `lead` should be used.

Comment: Hi @Andronicus, thanks. Seems perfect as workaround! Can I edit the question replacing 3 to 5, to be more didactic?

Comment: @PeterKrauss I'm glad you like it! Honestly I'd rather you don't change it, You can see the whole definition of mode and the query will be less readable. The only change would be for odd length of window - that would be the mid element in the first query

Comment: Hum... Details, no important, only maybe little issues for first (main) solution ... **1.** as I used `order by x`, it can be used at `w`; **2.**  ideal, to be didactic or to use template-solution, is to comment the parity of *L*, the length of the window, and the choice of *floor(L/2)* in the parameter, e.g.  `lag(x, floor(L/2.))` when *L* is odd. ... Or maybe starting with the general solution, defined [in the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) as  `( lag(x, floor((L+1)/2.)) + lag(x, ceil((L+1)/2.)) )/2`, so you can express odd and even cases as simplifications.

Comment: @PeterKrauss I have elaborated a bit about the more general case, I hope it's sufficient :)

Comment: This answer is good to big windows on Big Data, and to remember that *PostgreSQL developers* can optimize the *aggregate median()*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SELF-JOIN** and **GROUP BY**. An example of 4-period rolling median:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT s.e, s.i
    FROM generate_series(0.5, 10, 0.5) WITH ORDINALITY AS s (e, i)
)
SELECT t1.i,
    percentile_cont(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t2.e) AS median
FROM t AS t1
JOIN t AS t2 ON t2.i <= t1.i AND t2.i > t1.i - 4
GROUP BY t1.i;
```

Output is following:

[image]